# PHP/My SQL Database -> to Arduino Serial Monitor

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I'm using this domain http://www.decathlon.commonarchitecture.ca/ to host my phpmyadmin database and php code. I would like to read a specific column of the database in the serial monitor, displaying each number one right after the other. I'm unsure of whether to work with a GSM shield, an Ethernet shield or an Arduino wifi shield. Here is my php code (indents are off I know):

```
<?php

 $dbhost = "mysql.commonarchitecture.ca";
 $username = "arduinodb";
 $password = "*******";
 $db = "arduinodb" ;

    mysql_connect("$dbhost" , "$username" , "$password");
     //echo "Connected" ; 

    //select db
    mysql_select_db($db);
    //echo "Connected to db" ;

  $sql="SELECT * FROM data";

  $records=mysql_query($sql);

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <title> Consumption Data </title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing"1">

 <tr>

 <th>Day</th>
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>Water Consumption (liters per person)</th>

 <tr>

 <?php

    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {

         echo "<tr>";

         echo "<td>".$data['id']."</td>";

         echo "<td>".$data['date']."</td>";

         echo "<td>".$data['value']."</td>";

         echo "</tr>";

     }//end while

     ?>

 </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The code works, however I'm unsure of how to go about reading the data on an Arduino (very new to Arduino)

Here's my Arduino code paired with an ethernet shield

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>


byte mac[] = {   0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress ip(192, 168, *, *);

EthernetClient client;

char server[] = "www.decathlon.commonarchitecture.ca";


void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);

  // attempt a DHCP connection:
  Serial.println("Attempting to get an IP address using DHCP:");
  if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
  // if DHCP fails, start with a hard-coded address:
  Serial.println("failed to get an IP address using DHCP, trying 
  manually");
     Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }

  Serial.print("My address:");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop()
{
    // connect to the server
    if (client.connect(server, 80))
    {
        // print to serial monitor
        Serial.println("connected...");
        Serial.println("ARDUINO: forming HTTP request message");

        // send data the server through GET request
        client.print("GET /index.php?value");
        client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
        client.print("HOST:  ");
        client.println(server);

        Serial.println("ARDUINO: HTTP message sent");       

        // give server time to receive request
        delay(1000);

        // get the response from the page and print it to serial port
        // to ascertain that request was received properly
        if(client.available())
        {
            Serial.println("ARDUINO: HTTP message received");
            Serial.println("ARDUINO: printing received headers and 
script response...\n");

            while(client.available())
            {
                char c = client.read();
                Serial.print(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("ARDUINO: no response received / no response 
received in time");
        }

        client.stop();
    }
    // do nothing forever after:
    while(true);
}
```

My issue now is in getting the Arduino to read my php data, can I not use an http GET request to display data in my serial monitor? Am I using this function properly? There's a ton of documentation on posting Arduino sensor data to the web using php/my sql but not as much on retrieval of set data back into the serial monitor. Here's what the monitor reads currently...

```
Attempting to get an IP address using DHCP:
My address:192.168.*.*
connected...
ARDUINO: forming HTTP request message
ARDUINO: HTTP message sent
ARDUINO: no response received / no response received in time
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It's also a bad habit to get into doing things like `"$x"` when `$x` will suffice. Cleaner code is easier to follow along with and bugs are more obvious.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is Stack Overflow isn't a general advice forum, so if you're uncertain where to start you may need to find a place catering to Arduino specific answers like the [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com) where you can approach this from a more theoretical perspective.

Comment: One of the first times using PHP, thanks for the advice, definitely will take note not to use deprecated functions in the future if I continue with PHP experimentation. I've asked more about the Arduino on the stack exchange forum for Arduino, just wanted to know if what I hope to accomplish is feasible with the code and setup thus far and if anyone had any relevant  experiences.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're asking, but Stack Overflow has a pretty narrow mandate so it's just the wrong place to be asking it unless you've got some Arduino code you need help with. If that's the case, edit your question and add it to provide some more context. It's really hard to say if this will or won't work because there's no expectation here as to what the Arduino side has in the way of dependencies.

Comment: Noted! I've added my current Ethernet shield based Arduino code, thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Is that Arduino C++? Might merit a `C++` tag if that's the case, helps to get the right attention on the task at hand.